# java.sequence processing operators?

Tags: java

I know that the operators `&&`, `<<` is processed from left to right and `?:` - rigth to left.

So, my question: where i can find information about this?

I very need find information about this in official docs, but i cant find...

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/

Comment: I am pretty sure ?: is evaluated left to right. Otherwise you would evaluated the condition after evaluating the possible values.

Answer (score 1):

That `*` is processed before `+` in `a + b * c` is called "operator precedence"; `*` has higher precedence than `+`.

[The Java™ Tutorials - Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) (while not the authoritative documentation) lists the operator precedence in a table, and notes that

> All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.

---

The actual documentation is in [Java Language Specification Chapter 15 - Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html), but it is not at all readable. The documentation [notes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2) that

> **Precedence among operators is managed by a hierarchy of grammar
>   productions.** The lowest precedence operator is the arrow of a lambda
>   expression (->), followed by the assignment operators. Thus, all
>   expressions are syntactically included in the LambdaExpression and
>   AssignmentExpression nonterminals:

There is no table of operator precedence in the Java Language Specification itself; instead the operator precedence is revealed indirectly in the grammar productions.